# I can't do a school assignment. SQLite Help Needed

Tags: sql, sqlite

The table tests contains data on power tests of a certain type of rocket engine. The values ​​in the following columns mean:

```
ID - test number
SN - engine serial number
T - test duration in seconds
M1, M2, M3 - power values ​​recorded at the beginning, half and end of the test duration.
```

Your task is to display for each engine the test in which it achieved the highest average value of three power measurements. However, you must take into account the following limitations: 1.we are only interested in those engines that have participated in at least 5 tests, 2.of the tests for engines that meet condition 1, we are only interested in those that lasted at least a minute and where the lowest value of the three measurements was not less than 90% of the highest value of the three measurements 3. We are interested only in those engines for which the tests selected after meeting the criteria in point 2 meet the following condition: the lowest average of the three measurement results of the tests for a given engine is not less than 85% of the highest average of measurements among these tests.

The resulting table should contain four columns:

```
ID
SN
MAX - containing the highest value of the three measurements in the given test
MAX_AVG - containing the highest average of measurements from all tests for a given engine (taking into account the conditions described above). Round this value to two decimal places.
Sort the results from the highest to the lowest average.
```

I am a student and the professor gave me such an assignment below I am sending my idea to solve this problem.

```
SELECT
  ID, SN, AS MAX(M1, M2, M3) AS MAX, ROUND(MAX((M1 + M2 + M3)/3.0),2) AS MAX_AVG
FROM
  tests
WHERE
      T >= 60
  AND MIN(M1, M2, M3) >= MAX(M1, M2, M3) * 0.9
GROUP BY
  SN
HAVING
      COUNT(SN) >= 5
  AND MIN((M1 + M2 + M3)/3.0) >= MAX((M1 + M2 + M3)/3.0) * 0.85
ORDER BY
  MAX_AVG ASC;
```

Comment: What results did you get from your query? How do they differ from what you want?

Answer (score 1):

You do not say what your difficulty is. But you *did* include your attempt, and made an effort.

However, you have a condition backwards, so that might be it.

Say that you have an engine that participated in 5 tests, but the fifth only lasted 55 seconds. Condition 1 says that you must include that engine, because it did participate to five tests:

> 1.we are only interested in those engines that have participated in at least 5 tests

Of course, for that engine, you only want the first four tests:

> 2.of the tests for engines that meet condition 1, we are only interested in those that lasted at least a minute

But your WHERE excludes the fifth test from the start, so that leaves four, and the HAVING excludes that engine.

You probably want to try a subSELECT to handle this case.

Comment: I am using a site that generates jobs to solve on sqlite engine. the query should follow the command, however when I type my query it displays one record and a message that the job is not done correctly. what do you think is the solution to this problem or how would you use subSELECT

Comment: You'd need to add the schema and sample data to your question. And of course the intended result. Otherwise, the question as it stands would not really be useful to anyone except you - and that's not really what SO is all about.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH
  test_level_summary AS
(
  SELECT
    ID,
    SN,
    MIN(M1, M2, M3)                   AS MIN_M,
    MAX(M1, M2, M3)                   AS MAX_M,
    ROUND((M1 + M2 + M3)/3.0), 2)     AS AVG_M,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY SN)   AS SN_TEST_COUNT
  FROM
    tests
),
    valid_engines AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    MIN(AVG_M) OVER (PARTITION BY SN)   AS MIN_AVG_M,
    MAX(AVG_M) OVER (PARTITION BY SN)   AS MAX_AVG_M
  FROM
    test_level_summary
  WHERE
        SN_TEST_COUNT >= 5
    AND T >= 60
    AND MIN_M >= MAX_M * 0.9
)
SELECT
  ID, SN, MAX_M, AVG_M
FROM
  valid_engines
WHERE
      MIN_AVG_M >= MAX_AVG_M * 0.85
  AND     AVG_M  = MAX_AVG_M
```

Comment: The major difference here is that the MIN_AVG_M and MAX_AVG_M (used for constraint 3 from your question) are calculated only AFTER constraint 2 has been applied, and so excluded some tests from said calculation.

Comment: Oh, and that the MAX_M from the test with the highest AVG_M isn't necessarily the MAX(MAX_M).  For example if a test has M's of 100,101,102 and another test has M's of 100,100,103...then the first test has the highest AVG, but it's MAX_M isn't equal to MAX(MAX_M)